# Does "weighted clubs" refer to gyms in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I am reading an article from *1843 Magazine* and the title is "Suffering from shortages? How to survive without puppies, fake tan or IKEA."

One of the stories is about the childhood of Queen Victoria. It mentions the notorious Kensington System devised by her mother. One of the rules is workouts with ***weighted clubs***.

I don't know whether weighted clubs refer to gyms? But it is unlikely there were gyms back then. Does this mean some fitness equipment placed in Kensington Palace?

Comment: "I am reading an article"  Please provide a link to the article.

Comment: The use of the word "gymnasium" for a place of exercise comes from ancient Greece. Gyms was around long before the Victorians and were actually enjoying a rise in popularity when Queen Victoria was young.

Comment: Emma, you might not know that "club" has two totally different meanings.  One is a "stick" you whack people with!  Like you see cave-men holding in cartoons  :)  https://media.istockphoto.com/id/467210619/photo/caveman-shouting-and-holding-a-club.jpg?s=612x612&w=0&k=20&c=tM2wqJuGcg6ZMuTiik7cG-gUlV9Uw2uOyy5cLut49Pk=

Comment: I had to look that up because my first thought was how a magazine from 1843 would have references to fake tans or IKEA in it.  Puppies, Queen Victoria, sure, that made sense.  (Yeah, I know now that's the year the publisher was founded, but still a strange name for a magazine...)

Comment: Looks like this is the article, but it requires a login. https://www.economist.com/1843/2021/11/25/suffering-from-shortages-how-to-survive-without-puppies-fake-tan-or-ikea

Answer (score 28):

In this case, *club* has this meaning:

> 1 a : a heavy usually tapering staff especially of wood wielded as a weapon

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/club)

A *weighted* club would be a club (a tapering wooden staff) that has been *weighted*, as in, constructed to be heavy.

There are different kinds of weighted clubs that are (or were) used as exercise equipment.  The ones Queen Victoria would have used would have been

> **Indian clubs**, which originated in the Indian subcontinent, are a type of exercise equipment used to present resistance in movement to develop strength and mobility. They consist of juggling-club shaped wooden clubs of varying sizes and weights, which are swung in certain patterns as part of a strength exercise program...
>
> Exceptionally popular during the fitness movement of the late Victorian era, used by military cadets and well-heeled ladies alike, they appeared as a gymnastic event in the 1904 and 1932 Olympics.

[Wikipedia - Indian Club](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_club)

Comment: +1 If you think about it, today's [barbell-style exercise weights](https://www.amazon.com/Amazon-Adjustable-Barbell-Lifting-Dumbbells/dp/B0BNKMX3LH) are just specialized forms of weighted clubs.

Comment: @JBH I think the Victorian ones are due a comeback  - after all, we've got dumbbells, barbells, and kettlebells (Wikipedia says I'm not alone in thinking that).

Comment: A fitness regimen could always use More Cowbell